# How can I get the start and end date of all the months of current year and previous year?

Tags: php

I need help to create an array using php via loop that will store the number of seconds of start and end of all the months of current and previous year. The array will look somewhat like this.

```
   $dates = array(
    'previous dates' => array( 
                        'November, 2017' => array( 
                                            'start' => 1512082800, 
                                            'end' => 1514674800),
                        'December, 2017' => array( 
                                            'start' => 1512082800, 
                                            'end' => 1514674800)
                        ),

    'current dates' => array( 
                        'January, 2018' => array( 
                                            'start' => 1512082800, 
                                            'end' => 1514674800),
                        'February, 2018' => array( 
                                            'start' => 1512082800, 
                                            'end' => 1514674800)
                            )
    )
```

Comment: You should mention what you've tried already, it will make it easier to help you...

Comment: My solutions were all over the place and I am in bit of a hurry.  I will of course remember and try me best next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array();
for ($year=2017; $year<=2018; $year++) {
    $yearOfDates = array();
    for ($month=1; $month<=12; $month++) {
        $begin = strtotime($year."-".$month."-01 12:00:00AM");
        $end = strtotime($year."-".($month+1)."-01 12:00:00AM")-1;
        $key = date("F, Y", $begin); // January, 2017
        $yearOfDates[$key] = array(
            'start' => $begin,
            'end' => $end
        );
    }
    if ($year==2017) $dates['previous year'] = $yearOfDates;
    else $dates['current year'] = $yearOfDates; //assume 2018
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mean this year specifically but it will help

Comment: You can always use time() to find out the current year and adjust. I went based off the example you gave.If you found my answer satisfactory, please accept it as the solution. Thanks.